# Java 11 , get timezone of users local machine

Tags: java, timezone

We are developing applications where dates are stored in GMT , and need is to display date and time according to users local clock timezone

Java 11 , when i change timezone , its requires JVM restart so its taking old timezone of during start of server.

Is there any ways to determine timezone of machine ( OS) without restarting JVM?

Code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(" -- " + TimeZone.getDefault());
        long milliDiff = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
        // Got local offset, now loop through available timezone id(s).
        String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        String name = null;
        for (String id : ids) {
            System.out.println("ID  : " + id);
            TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
            System.out.println("TZ : " + tz.getRawOffset());
            if (tz.getRawOffset() == milliDiff) {
                // Found a match.
                name = id;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Name " + name);
```

Above code works OK as standalone, but when intregrated in web application ( JVM ) its KO.

Comment: "but when intregrated in web application ( JVM ) its KO." I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZoneId` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What do you need the server time zone for? And why are you ever changing the server time zone? Can you explain your problem better, because I don’t understand it? Am I correct in assuming that the server time zone and the user’s time zone may be different?

Comment: There probably is a way to determine the operating system time zone, and it probably is OS dependent. So search for how to do it with your server OS.

Comment: WHat i have done , i have used Javascript to fetch users timezone ( clock) and passed that to a ajax call that stores the TZ in session , and use this TZ to convert dates to desired timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## java.time

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### Avoid setting default time zone

No need to set the current default time zone of your JVM. Doing so is risky as you immediately affect all other code in all threads running in all apps in that JVM. And doing so is unreliable in that any code in any thread of any app in that JVM can change the zone at any moment behind your back.

### `Instant`

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds) using `Instant` class.

```java
Instant now = Instant.now();
System.out.println( "now = " + now );
```

> now.toString() = 2023-02-16T06:24:54.944850Z

### `ZoneId`

Time zones are represented by the [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) class.

Use [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `Africa/Casablanca`, `Europe/Berlin`, `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use 2-4 character pseudo-zones such as `CST`, `IST`, etc.

```java
Set < String > zoneNames = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
for ( String zoneName : zoneNames )
{
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( zoneName );
    ZonedDateTime zdt = now.atZone( z );
    System.out.println( "Now in zone " + z + " is " + zdt.toString() );
}
```

```
Now in zone Asia/Aden is 2023-02-16T09:24:54.944850+03:00[Asia/Aden]
Now in zone America/Cuiaba is 2023-02-16T02:24:54.944850-04:00[America/Cuiaba]
…
Now in zone Pacific/Guadalcanal is 2023-02-16T17:24:54.944850+11:00[Pacific/Guadalcanal]
Now in zone Europe/Athens is 2023-02-16T08:24:54.944850+02:00[Europe/Athens]
Now in zone US/Pacific is 2023-02-15T22:24:54.944850-08:00[US/Pacific]
Now in zone Europe/Monaco is 2023-02-16T07:24:54.944850+01:00[Europe/Monaco]
```

### Current moment as seen by user

You asked:

> need is to display date and time according to users local clock timezone

Capture the [current default time zone of the JVM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()) at runtime.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

However, if critical, your app should confirm the user's intended time zone.

[Adjust our `Instant` object to that zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#atZone(java.time.ZoneId)). Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Or skip over the `Instant` object to [get `ZonedDateTime` directly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now(java.time.ZoneId)).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```